# How to perform the query to display the user information after authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

This is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var passport = require('passport');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  console.log("This is the value of authentuntication = " +req.isAuthenticated());
  res.render('home', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});

router.get('/profile/', authenticationMiddleware(),(req,res)=>{
  const db = require('../db.js');
 // var user_id = req.params.id;
  res.render('profile',{title:'Profile'});
  console_log("This is inside get router profile: "+req.user);
});

router.get('/login', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('login',{title:'login'});
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect:'/profile/',
  failureRedirect:'/login'
}));

router.get('/logout', (req,res)=>{
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/register', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
    title: 'Registration'
  });
});

router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
  //using express validator to validate the data 
  req.checkBody('username', 'Username field cannot be empty.').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('username', 'Username must be between 4-15 characters long.').len(4, 15);
  req.checkBody('email', 'The email you entered is invalid, please try again.').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email address must be between 4-100 characters long, please try again.').len(4, 100);
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password must be between 8-100 characters long.').len(8, 100);
  req.checkBody("password", "Password must include one lowercase character, one uppercase character, a number, and a special character.").matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/, "i");
  req.checkBody('passwordMatch', 'Password must be between 8-100 characters long.').len(8, 100);
  req.checkBody('passwordMatch', 'Passwords do not match, please try again.').equals(req.body.password);
  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
   // console.log(`errors:${JSON.stringify(errors)}`);
    res.render('register', {
      title: 'Registration Error',
      errors: errors
    });
  } else {
    //storing the data comming form post resquest 
    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const db = require('../db.js');

    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
      // Store hash in your password DB.
      let sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
      db.query(sql, [username, email, hash], (error, result, fields) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        db.query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as user_id', (error, result, field) => {
          if (error) throw error;

          const user_id = result[0];
         // console.log(result[0]);
          req.login(user_id, (err) => {
            res.redirect("/");
          });
        });

      });
    });
  }
});

passport.serializeUser(function (user_id, done) {
  done(null, user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user_id, done) {
  done(null, user_id);
});

function authenticationMiddleware() {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`req.session.passport.user: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}`);
    console.log(`My user id is :  ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`);

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}
module.exports = router;
```

I want to get the id of the user that just logged in and use that id to do a query into the database and pull the information about the users in to the profile.hbs. something like this.

```
router.get('/profile/', authenticationMiddleware(),(req,res)=>{
  const db = require('../db.js');
 // var user_id = req.params.id;
  res.render('profile',{title:'Profile'});
  console_log("This is inside get router profile: "+req.user);
  /*db.query('SELECT * from users where id = ?', user_id, function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error ocurred while getting user details of " + user_id, error);
        res.send({
            "code": 400,
            "failed": "error ocurred"
        });
    } else {
        res.render("profile",{user:results});
    }
  });*/
});
```

I can see id of the user in the  console.log(`My user id is :  ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`); which is inside my authenticationMiddleware() functions but after that i dont know how to pass that id into the /profile router that loads the profile.

Comment: Try the request promise native approach . https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise. In this u can tie ur input to the next request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your db.js holds.. but in theory, you would want your code to look like (notice .then func returning from .getUser, meaning it has async/await pattern or returns a promise in lehman words):

```
const db = require('../db');
router.get('/profile/', authenticationMiddleware(),(req, res, next) => {
   db.getUser(userId).then((userData) => {
      res.render("profile",{user:results});
   }).catch(next)
});

// define an app level error catch
// to produce unified error screens
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
   res.send({
     "code": 400,
     "failed": "error ocurred"
    });
});
```

Comment: @ Ady Levy db.getUser is for mono db, i am using  mysql here is my db.js `var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database : process.env.DB_NAME
})

connection.connect();
/*
connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});*/

module.exports = connection;`

Answer (score 0):

db.getUser is a facade method. could be used with any DB so that the app is not aware of it's DB.

For sql, you need to encapsulate your query with a promise - something like:

```
const getUser( userId ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      const sqlQuery = 'select ....';
      connection.query( sqlQuery, args, ( err, rows ) => {
          if ( err )
              return reject( err );
            resolve( rows );
        } );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking @Ady Levy soultions, I came up with this soultion and i worked perfectly for me. I am new to node and express so i dont understand encapsulating with promise.

```
[![router.get('/profile/', authenticationMiddleware(),(req, res, next) => {
  //console.log("router.get/profile/ : "+ req.user.user_id);
  //res.render('profile',{title:'Profile'});
  var userId = req.user.user_id;
  console.log(userId);
  const db = require('../db.js');
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users where id = ?',\[userId\], (err,results,fields)=>{
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error occured while getting the user detail of " + userId, err);
    }
    else{
      res.render('profile',{title:'Profile',user_detail:results\[0\]});
      //console.log(results\[0\]);
    }

  });
});][1]][1]
```